# Copy a file in ruby as sudo user

Tags: ruby

I am trying to copy a file from a source to destination, but the copy is failing with `fileutils.rb:1402:in`initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen`.

The destination file is owned by root, where as the script is running under a different local user.  How do I do the copy as sudo root?

Here is my current code

```
FileUtils.cp("#{Dir.home}/.user.crt", "#{'/opt/vagrant/embedded/.user.crt'}")
puts "Copied cert file"
```

Error encountered

```
fileutils.rb:1402:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen  - /opt/vagrant/embedded/.user.crt (Errno::EACCES)
```

Comment: You should run the script as a user who has access to both directories

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `sudo` gem](https://github.com/gderosa/rubysu) to give individual objects sudo access.

```
require 'sudo'
Sudo::Wrapper.run do |sudo|
  sudo[FileUtils].cp("#{Dir.home}/.user.crt", '/opt/vagrant/embedded/.user.crt')
end
```

This is more secure than running the whole script under elevated privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
I tried this snippet of code, but I am getting a new error
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sudo (LoadError)
 from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 from configure-env1.rb:109:in `<main>'

Comment: @Alex That somewhat cryptic message means you didn't [install the sudo gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/).

Comment: I installed the sudo gem and all is working now. Thanks for the solution.